# Assign value to method invocation

Tags: java, methods, hashmap, invoke, getter

For later reference:

```
Operations o = new Operations(); //class containing the operation methods
HashMap<String, Method> ops = new HashMap<String, Method>();
```

---

I'm working on a program that will parse a mathematical expression input via console or eventually maybe a GUI.

Currently, I have a class called "Operations" which has various basic math functions (more will be added later, just testing right now). In another class, I have a method which calculates the result by taking an operand, the successive operator, and another operand, and invoking a method to evaluate the expression. It stores the info necessary to the calculation in:

```
double numOne = //...
char operator = //...
double numTwo = //...
double result = //...
```

Now I don't want to have a long `switch`/`case` statement or `if` statement saying:

```
if (operator.equals("+")) //I know .equals() doesn't use chars; it's an example
     o.add(numOne, numTwo);
else if (operator.equals("-"))
     o.subtract(numOne, numTwo);
```

on and on for every operation. That's why I tried creating a `HashMap<String, Method>` to store the operator (String) and the method which should be called. Basically, in the current class' constructor, I put:

```
ops.put("+", o.getClass().getMethod("add", double.class, double.class));
ops.put("-", o.getClass().getMethod("subtract", double.class, double.class));
//etc. Which in and of itself is also pretty lengthy
```

Now to once the method is identified via operator, I need another method to return a `Method` to call.

```
private Method getMethodFromKey(HashMap<String, Method> map, char op) {
    Method method = null;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Method> e: map.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getKey().equals(op))
            method = e.getValue();
    }
    return method;
}
```

Finally, once I have the correct method, I can call it with:

```
getMethodFromKey(ops, operator).invoke(o, numOne, numTwo);
```

That all works great. My problem is, the method(s) I am/will be invoking are getter methods; they return a double. Example:

```
public double add(double one, double two) {
    double answer = 0;
    answer = one + two;
    return answer;
}
```

I guess this is all just a long-winded way of asking is there a way to assign the returned value of an innvoked method? Something like:

```
result = getMethodFromKey(ops, operator).invoke(o, numOne, numTwo); //This doesn't work :(
```

Any help is appreciated. Additionally, if my aproach is completely wrong, I would appreciate a bump in the right direction.

---

DISCLAIMER: I'm relatively inexperienced at Java and known for overcomplicating things, so please point out any grievous flaws in my design. :)

Comment: Exactly what's the error you get when executing getMethodFromKey()?

Comment: It should work. `invoke` returns on `Object` which is in case the original method returns `double` boxed into a `Double`. To get the `double` back cast it like `double result = (Double) invoke()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invoke()` returns `Object` and since Java does not know how to assign an `Object` to a `double` this won't compile. `invoke` starts by boxing the `double` from the method into a `Double`. You have to cast it now from `Object` to `Double` (and could then call `.doubleValue()` but that's done automatically) for that to work.

> I'm [...] known for overcomplicating things, so please point out any grievous flaws in my design. :)

Using reflection instead of an interface. A `Method` is a function object. But it's not type-safe to use. An interface can do the same without those problems.

```
interface Operation {
    double evaluate(double a, double b);
}
```

Then put objects that implement the interface in your map:

```
ops.put("+", new Operation() {
    public double evaluate(double a, double b) {
        return a+b;
    });
```

and you can do

```
double result = getMethodFromKey(ops, operator).evaluate(numOne, numTwo);
```

The need to cast is gone.

Answer (score 1):

If `invoke()` is returning an `Object` that you know is a `double`, you can cast it like so:

```
result = (Double) getMethodFromKey(ops, operator).invoke(o, numOne, numTwo);
```

Since `double` is a primitive, which is not of type `Object`, you need to cast it to a `Double`, and through [unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), we get a `double`.

Comment: Sorry for my bad wording. By "works", I meant "doesn't cause an error". I believe the original works because it is simply calling the method. When I try the second one, it says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to double"

Comment: @RuandeVilliers You need to post the `invoke` method.

Comment: Here's an example of one of the methods:
`public double add(double one, double two) {
  double answer = 0;
  answer = one + two;
  return answer;
 }`
Sorry, the formatting for the above code didn't really work

Comment: @RuandeVilliers I don't under what you're saying.  Neither of those methods are in the line you posted. `getMethodFromKey()` returns a `Method`, which calls `invoke()`.  If `invoke()` returns a `double`, this should work.  Since you haven't posted `invoke()` I can't say anymore.

Comment: I used java.lang.reflect.Method for the "Method" class and "invoke" method; I didn't write them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that all of your operations are going to be on a single class (no extensibility), then you should consider using an `enum` instead. You can [add an instance field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to the `enum` to represent the character command corresponding to the operation and then have an abstract `evaluate` method that's implemented by each `enum` value.

Comment: I don't know much about `enums`, but the operators will be input as `+, -, *, /, etc.` For example: `3 + (4 - 8) / 6` Don't think I can use reserved characters for `enum` fields

Comment: You would have an enum with a field `char command` and instances `ADD('+')`, `SUBTRACT('-')`, and so on.

Comment: Can you point me somewhere I can learn a little more about enums? The Java documentation's wording is a little confusing for me :(

Comment: Also, some of my functions are `power(...)` and `root(...)` Not sure how to store both `chars` and `Strings` in the same `enum` Pardon my ignorance if I'm not understanding something simple, but haven't had much education in the field of Comp. Sci.

Comment: Just use a `String` field instead of a `char` one. Don't worry; Java's full-class `enum`s are a powerful but subtle feature. Remember that an `enum` is a full class and each value is a regular class instance, so you can have member variables (like a `String` to hold the command) and override methods (like `evaluate`). The trick, which you'll have to deal with regardless of implementation method, is function arity.